# Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot when vagrant up

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vagrant, ubuntu-13.10

I have an Ubuntu 13.10 and I installed Vagrant 1.5.4 and VirtualBox 4.3.10r93012. My problem occurs when I write the command `vagrant up` at the first time the script up the virtual machine correctly. But after doing `vagrant halt` and write the command `vagrant up` again, a problem occurs:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Is there any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I increase the time using `config.vm.boot_timeout`. But for me it was not the reason although the error tells about a timeout.

I opened the Vagrantfile using vim and add the following lines which turns on GUI for the VM.

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```

After re-running the `vagrant up` i saw the real reason in the GUI. There was an error dialog and it keeps waiting. That was the reason for the connection timeout.

To fix this i had to do some configurations in the system BIOS. I had to turn on the  intel VT-x setting. And please check for AMD-V setting as well. These settings help hardware virtualization.

Comment: Thanks @Akalanka  for your comment. I solve the problem through turn on the intel VT-x BIOS's setting.

Comment: Ive enabled GUI, but in GUI i can see the login screen of the VM and i can login with user name and password both as vagrant. ssh timeouts.


    ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key

Comment: Thanks for the tip of showing the VirtualBox UI! In my case everything was normal, no found errors, so increasing the timeout was enough.

**IMPORTANT:** I have realized about that I only had the timeout problem when disconnecting the laptop from the electricity apparentlly because after doing that the laptop enters in a "battery saver" mode. When it is connected to electricity it is in a "performance" mode and then I never have the problem.

Comment: Where is config file? How can I find vagrantfile?

Answer (score 39):

Select your Ubuntu server, click on Settings, go to Network tab and make sure that your **Cable Connected** option is selected.

[image]

Comment: After fighting tooth and nail with this problem, this solution worked for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks a million man! I was stuck up with this the whole day! :)

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: Update your Virtual Box. Move to VB 5 or something. It should work.

Comment: In my case "Cable connected" is already selected! Answer by @Akalanka helped, but vagrant up is very slow.

Comment: You can set "Cable connected" to true within the Vagrantfile btw. Add `vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected1", "on" ]` to the `config.vm.provider` section.

Answer (score 14):

I used "vagrant destroy" and solved the problem.

This command stops the running machine Vagrant is managing and destroys all resources that were created during the machine creation process. After running this command, your computer should be left at a clean state, as if you never created the guest machine in the first place.

Comment: To me "vagrant desroy" was not an option and wanted to try. It would remove lots of work. I tried "vagrant reload"  and  that worked.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem on windows 10 and the solution for me was to enable **Intel Virtualization**.

I'm afraid I can't give you specific instructions, as far as the BIOS menu options vary from computer to computer depending on the manufacturer. However, generally you should follow these steps:

1-Power on the machine and open the BIOS.

2- Open the Processor submenu. The processor settings menu may be hidden in the Chipset, Advanced CPU Configuration or Northbridge.

3-Enable Intel Virtualization Technology (also known as Intel VT) or AMD-V depending on the brand of the processor.

4- Save the changes and restart.

Comment: Thanks, I think that it's the best option to solve the problem if BIOS supports this configuration. If it doesn't support, a possible solution is via vagrant config as @Akalanka said.

Comment: But not everybody can access their BIOS. I can't.

Comment: This worked for me on my laptop. After enabling IVT in BIOS vagrant command worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You need to able the GUI. Remove the comment of this lines in your `Vagrant` file:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```

After you need shutdown your machine and start again:

```
vagrant halt
vagrant up
```

Comment: Any ideas why that would be necessary?

Comment: Wow. Over 5 years later and is still a valid workaround ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @noelicus glad that was useful for you.

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting error message `Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot.` After enabling the GUI through vagrant file, I could see that vagrant tp was asking for login & password. providing `vagrant/vagrant` worked but the machine was still not up.

Finally, `Vagrant destroy` worked. After this vagrant up provisioned machine & now I could do ssh.

Comment: For me, I turned on the vb.gui and saw that it had problems with the disk drive boot, and that the /tmp folder is not yet ready or present. Doing a `vagrant destroy` took  care of that problem.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I recently ran into this same issue with an Ubuntu vagrant box (19.04) and wanted to post the solution that worked for me.

The key part was the number of cpus. The box had been trying to boot with 2 enabled and that was absolutely killing the performance during boot, so much so that vagrant would time out waiting.

By setting it to 1 my box came up immediately on vagrant up!

In your Vagrantfile under the `config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|` section try adding `v.cpus = 1` and see if that helps.

Hope this helps someone else having a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks, this is the ONLY thing that worked for me. Everything else here was a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

I had tried everything but didn't work for me any solution. Then i had found this solution on github. Check the solution.

#### Option 1:

1. Restart and keep pressing F10 to open BIOS settings.
2. Open Advanced CPU Configuration. (Try to find Virtualization technology settings.)
3. Enable Intel Virtualization Technology (also known as Intel VT) depending on the brand.
4. Save the changes and restart.

#### Option 2:

1. Open up the command prompt of your windows. You should open terminal or command prompt as an administrator and then
   then type:

   ```
   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
   ```
2. Restart your computer.

find more details from this [blog](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4587#issuecomment-511230925)

Comment: I did Option 2 and it worked for me. It took 4 hours of my life.

Comment: I see! I had also wasted lots of time. That's why i put on my solution here.

Answer (score 2):

You probably enabled firewall which is causing the problem.
Just add

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```

to your VagrantFile then vagrant up. Login wth vagrant credentials on the gui window and disable the firewall with `sudo ufw disable`.

Restart vagrant and everything should be fine.

```
vagrant halt
vagrant up
```

Comment: good point but, no need to launch the heavy UI though... just `vagrant ssh` and then `sudo ufw disable` as you said

Answer (score 2):

**I had the same issue on a Windows 10**

```
 default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...

 default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222

 default: SSH username: vagrant

 default: SSH auth method: private key Timed out while waiting for the 
machine to boot. This means that Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
```

**And this solution worked for me :**

Open up the command prompt of your windows as an administrator and run :

```
 bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Restart your computer.

Answer (score 1):

just enable virtualization technology of cpu setting in BIOS

Answer (score 1):

Just paste this code in your variant file and it will work fine.

```
config.vm.boot_timeout = "1440"
```

After saving changes, enter the vagrant provision command to update changes
Then run vagrant ssh to start a homestead

Answer (score 0):

Edit `config.vm` and increase the value of `config.vm.boot_timeout` to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**Potential Issue:** Virtualization might be disabled in your bios

Restart your computer and keep hitting F10 key. This will take you into the system BIOS. There you can check if your Intel-Virtualization is disabled. If so, change it to Enabled, save and continue to restart your pc.

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequisite**: Please Make sure your virtualization is enabled.

I had the same problem in my windows 10 system and I researched a lot about the issue in both StackOverflow and GitHub issues but nothing worked. So I simply **updated my virtual box** to the latest version and **rebooted** the system. Afterwards, it worked absolutely fine for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Few things you can try:

1. Check the Vagrant version (`vagrant -v`) you are running and it should be latest. Also run `vagrant box update`.
2. Increase `config.vm.boot_timeout` value in Vagrantfile.
3. Add `vb.gui = true` after `config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|`  line in Vagrantfile to open VM with GUI.  Try reload, and see what is the exact error at which it is getting stuck and try fixing that.
   Also click on Settings, go to Network tab and make sure that your Cable Connected option is selected.

   [image]
4. Once GUI is enabled try reloading and once the login screen is up, you can login with the username vagrant and the password is the same as the username. You need to open up `/etc/default/grub`. Add the following to the bottom of the file and save the file: `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=2`. Run `sudo update-grub`. Shutdown the VM and run `vagrant up`.

Comment: For me solution was step 3 and reloading vagrant.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up`
The drawback is it deletes all the database and you need to run your migrations again.