# Vagrant up timeout

Tags: timeout, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

Having some issues to get my vagrant up, 
Got the box, run `vagrant init` and after `vagrant up` command I get this message.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> default: Importing base box 'precise32'...
    ==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
    ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: virtm_default_1400193131859_61200
    ==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2201.
    ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
        default: Adapter 1: nat
    ==> default: Forwarding ports...
        default: 22 => 2201 (adapter 1)
    ==> default: Booting VM...
    ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
        default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2201
        default: SSH username: vagrant
        default: SSH auth method: private key 
    Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

    If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

    If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes. Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly, as well.

    If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293071/timed-out-while-waiting-for-the-machine-to-boot-when-vagrant-up/39892470#39892470

Answer (score 23):

There are several different problems which can lead to this timeout problem. A good tip for tracking it down is to enable the GUI mode. This will bring up the VirtualBox machine UI which may provide a better clue as to the problem.

To enable GUI mode, make sure this section in your `Vagrantfile` is uncommented:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
   vb.gui = true
end
```

Then do a `vagrant reload`. This should bring up the VirtualBox application showing your virtual machine UI. Usually the problem will become apparent, whether it's a network issue or grub boot loader problem.

After fixing the issue, you can comment this out again, then do another `vagrant reload` to return to headless mode.

Reference: [Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the VM was stuck at the bootloader (grub) waiting for ENTER key. I am using the default `hashicorp/precise32`. 
I started the machine with GUI, then ran `sudo grub-mkconfig` that reset the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file, and I could then comment back the `vb.gui=true` line.

Comment: @maggix that's the same problem I had; I'm not 100% sure but I think it happened whenever starting a VM after it had been previously 'vagrant halt'; now I do a cleaner shutdown like: `vagrant ssh -c 'sudo shutdown -h now'`

Comment: Thanks @BrianC I will follow your advice if something goes wrong again!

Comment: I've done this and then what is described here in order to fix my issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10208#issuecomment-422626935

Answer (score 5):

A solution is gracefully described [here](https://pseudoscripter.wordpress.com/2016/10/23/vagrant-was-unable-to-communicate-with-the-guest-machine). It was the only one that worked for me on a i686 with Ubuntu 16.04.2, Vagrant 1.9.3 and Virtualbox 5.1.18 trying to run a ubuntu/trusty32.

What you do is fix the networking on the server and add some extra time for the boot:

- start the VM, log in to the server via GUI (username: vagrant, password: vagrant) and run the following commands

  ```
  $ sudo ifdown eth0
  $ sudo ifup eth0
  ```
- then add the following to the file /etc/rc.local

  ```
  ifdown eth0
  ifup eth0
  ```
- on the host, add the following to the Vagrantfile

  ```
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 600
  ```

Now stop the VM. Next time you do a 'vagrant up' it will be OK.

Comment: [EDIT] added a previously ommited step (the two sudo commands). Worked again OK. Had to wait a few minutes though.

Answer (score 4):

If your Vagrant box is running Ubuntu 16.04, it's because of this boot step ... **A start job is running for raise network interfaces (5 mins 8 sec)** One way to overcome this is to start the VM from VirtualBox and then do **vagrant ssh**

Answer (score 3):

`config.vm.boot_timeout` didn't help me even after setting up-to maximum!!!

The real problem in my case was, it was unable to create the network adapter. I have to explicitly edit the box.ovf file in order to enable it.

Locate the **box.ovf** file & open it in an text editor, then add `cable="true"` as shown in below, after that save and exit. Post that destroy your vagrant using vagrant destroy and then bring it up.

```
Locate(box.ovf): C:\Users\<use_name>\.vagrant.d\boxes\box-cutter-VAGRANTSLASH-centos68-desktop\2.0.21\virtualbox\box.ovf

Before: <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="084017AA8CEB" type="virtio">

After: <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="084017AA8CEB" cable="true" type="virtio">
```

There is a nice thread [here](https://github.com/chef/bento/issues/682)

Answer (score 2):

### Upgrade VirtualBox to 5.1.12

I had the same problem using:

- **VirtualBox 5.0.0**
- **Vagrant 1.9.1** (`vagrant -v`)
- **Test Kitchen 1.14.2** (`kitchen -v`)
- **centos-7.2**

when I was trying to run the following commands:

```
kitchen create
```

and

```
kitchen test
```

**Upgrading Oracle VirtualBox** (download + install) to [**VirtualBox 5.1.12**](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.12/VirtualBox-5.1.12-112440-Win.exe) fixed the problem.

---

If the upgrade is not a solution for you, you can use the following [**workaround**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39892470/3885376) mentioned by @paulalexandru, but it has the following main **disadvantage**: you need to make that manual step for every command that you are running.

---

But it seems that VirtualBox fixed the **"Cable Connected"** option problem. Now, if you go to **Settings** > **Network** > **Adapter 1** > **Advanced**, you can see that the **Cable Connected** check box is checked by default:

[image: Cable Connected is checked]

Comment: With 5.0.26r108824 I got the "Cable connected" disabled by default on the first of two network interfaces, over a freshly new created box running OpenSuse-42.2. It was not happening on OpenSuse Leap-42.1. But I can't confirm that the issue is with the OS version.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem that occurred to me. At last we found out that this problem is due to the Linux OS that we are using with Vagrant version is not compatible. So, we took the latest version (i.e. v1.6.3) of Vagrant and updated our OS to point to 
agent.vm.box_url =
"http://developer.nrel.gov/downloads/vagrant-boxes/CentOS-6.4-i386-v20131103.box"

Vagrant version 4.3.8 was not working with the below OS.
agent.vm.box_url = "http://developer.nrel.gov/downloads/vagrant-boxes/CentOS-6.4-x86_64-v20130731.box".

We exactly got the same issue that shown above.

Answer (score 0):

For me, enabling virtualization option from BIOS fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10.

I solved this problem by following the steps in the note

"If you are using Windows, you may need to enable hardware virtualization (VT-x). It can usually be enabled via your BIOS. If you are using Hyper-V on a UEFI system you may additionally need to disable Hyper-V in order to access VT-x."

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have uninstalled Docker-CE in my windows 10 then vagrant worked fine.
Also please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50119065/2682494) option disabled.

Answer (score 0):

with my setup, windows 11, vagrant 2.2.19:

I tried all the suggested solutions on the internet and all of them were useless to me, finally my problem was solved simply by changing the settings of Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager as follows: setting---> system ----> Processor --- -> Uncheck the box PAE / NX.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the WinRM timeout from 120 seconds to 25 minutes worked for me.

```
config.winrm.timeout =   1500 
config.vm.boot_timeout = 1500
```

Answer (score 0):

For me just running

```
vagrant reload
```

helped, since it seems that on the first start the box had older version of guest additions. By running vagrant reload, it was able to reboot the box and install newer version, and it started to work. vagrant destroy didn't help since it always had the older guest additions on the first boot.

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gux1t.png

Trying to use gui and still didnt help. Already triying to activate virtual machine on bios, disabled hypervisor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

With my setup Win10, Vagrant 2.1.2 and Ubuntu 16 while working firewall i have enabled "ufw" for port 80 post which i was facing same problem. Command used as below to enable firewall

```
ufw enable

ufw 80 allow
```

I did login in GUI enable mode in Vagrantfile and disabling the same is life saver for me.

```
ufw disable
```

Now, just do

```
vagrant reload

vagarnt ssh
```