# Timeout while trying to vagrant up

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm running out of ideas. I'm trying to follow the Laravel homestead tutorial to start using vagrant but I keep getting connection timeouts when I try to vagrant up..

I'm running Windows 7 on my physical host. I develop in an 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 VM and run vagrant inside of that. I'm not sure if this sort of VM Matryoshka doll setup is causing the issue or what.

I have additionally ensured that hardware virtualization is enabled in BIOS and enabled PAE/NX on both my guest Ubuntu VM and my homestead vagrant instance.

The issue is replicatable too. It's happening on my desktop and laptop with similar configurations in the exact same way.

The error I'm seeing is as follows:

> default: SSH username: vagrant
>
> default: SSH auth method: private key
>
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
>
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
>
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
>
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
>
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
>
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
>
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
>
> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
>
> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To troubleshoot startup timeout problems like this, I find it useful to enable the GUI mode so you can see if it's stuck during the boot cycle. I have some more details in this answer: [Vagrant up timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690124/vagrant-up-timeout/23742373#23742373)

+1 for Matryoshka doll reference :)