# Vagrant Laravel Homestead doesn't boot up [Windows-7]

Tags: laravel, windows-7, laravel-4, vagrant, 32-bit

### Context

I'm using `Vagrant 1.6.3` and `VirtualBox 4.3.14` on a `Windows 7` box.

- *Homestead.yaml* except:

> ```
> ---
> ip: "192.xxx.xxx.xxx"
> memory: 2048
> cpus: 1
>
> authorize: C:/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
>
> keys:
>     - C:/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> folders:
>     - map: D:/MyVagrant/Code
>       to: /home/vagrant/Code
>
> sites:
>     - map: homestead.app
>       to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
>
> variables:
>     - key: APP_ENV
>       value: local
> ```

---

### Issue

I can't get `Laravel Homestead` up and running.

Excerpt of the console output:

> ```
> ==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
> ==> default: Booting VM...
> ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
>     default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
>     default: SSH username: vagrant
>     default: SSH auth method: private key
>     default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
>     ... Idem - many times...
>     default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
> ```

---

### Question

How could it be fixed provided that Laravel Homestead is Windows 7 32-bit ready?

---

### Nota bene

This post is similar to "[Timeout while trying to vagrant up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555255/timeout-while-trying-to-vagrant-up)" but nevertheless it calls for the following observations:

- The latter didn't receive enough attention, no satistactory answer so far (as the time of the post)
- This one provides more (relevant) details.

---

### Updtate

My bad: I didn't provide sufficient details as I pretended: My computer has not a **VT-x** capable cpu!

Comment: You can try enabling `vb.gui = true` in Vagrantfile to get more information. Or try launching VM from VirtualBox GUI directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to this thread: [Trouble getting homestead to start in windows](http://laravel.io/forum/05-18-2014-trouble-getting-homestead-to-start-in-windows) in laravel.io forum.

To sum up:

Use a **custom settler** that you can find in Github instead of the default one: [antoniofrignani/laravel-homestead-settler-32](https://github.com/antoniofrignani/laravel-homestead-settler-32)

Steps:

1. Run `vagrant destroy`
2. Open the file `homestead.rb` in `Homestead/scripts` folder
3. Change `config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"` to `config.vm.box = "antoniofrignani/laravel-homestead-settler-32"`
4. Save `homestead.rb`
5. Run `vagrant up`

That's all! It works for us, our computer too doesn't support **Hardware-assisted virtualization**.

Answer (score 0):

### My finding:

Current Laravel Homestead version requires machine with **VT-x** capable cpu.

---

### Conclusion:

That rules out my box so far (Dual Core powered!). Still looking for workaround.

Comment: One thing you can try, if you are up for it, is make your own Homestead clone using the build script Taylor uses: https://github.com/laravel/settler.  Just change the box type on the Vagrant file to a 32 bit version and run this.  I used it to make a custom version of Homestead for my office with extra packages.  You can then re-package the box with the vagrant box options and end up having your own.

Comment: @noeldiaz: You made a very hard to meet assumption (at least for my case): To be - comfortable with/well versed in - [tag:vagrant]

Comment: I understand.  Took me a while to get going with it.  If you are willing to take a stab at it I just ran through the process and documented how to do it here:  https://gist.github.com/noeldiaz/0f9a2583a41579878764

Comment: If you do try it let me know if anything is unclear.  Might clean it up and make a blog post about it or something since I bet others are stuck with 32 bit systems too.  But this works.  Just ran a test site on it.

Comment: @noeldiaz: Nice. Thanks a lot for the pointer. It's a valuable resource.