# Laravel homestead stuck on VM login

Tags: laravel, vagrant

Ill try to use laravel homestead vagrant box. When I do vagrant up it stucks on 
`default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...`

My intel virtualization technology is enabled. I've enabled the GUI and it shows:

[image]

I've got `Vagrant 1.6.5` and `VirtualBox 4.3.16`.

Anybody has encountered this problem as well...?

Comment: Authentication to the VM is done through SSH keys, there is no username/password in order to login to the box (that I know of). There might be a method of adding your SSH key to VirtualBox and having it authenticate you once the box comes online, however it is very easy to do through the command line following the instructions on [Laravel's Homestead page](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead).

Comment: I've followed those, still not working.. I've did it like 10 times over and over..

Comment: homestead / homestead

Comment: vagrant / vagrant worked for me

Comment: @Alan That worked for me too. Thank you.

Answer (score 79):

Default login and password is just `vagrant`.

Answer (score 6):

A few things to try:

1. First, make sure your virtual machine is completely shut down, and relaunch Virtual Box.
2. Make sure "PAE/NX" is enabled, which you can do in the processor tab
   of the Virtual Box GUI. [A description of how to do that is
   here.](https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=1691-homestead-connection-timeout/0)
3. When `vagrant up` gets stuck at `Warning: Connection refused.
   Retrying...`, try entering `vagrant` as both the username and
   password in the GUI and see if it will continue the loading process.
4. See related StackOverflow questions [Vagrant stuck connection
   timeout
   retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying)
   and [Vagrant up
   timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690124/vagrant-up-timeout/23742373#23742373).

Answer (score 3):

Also just in case check if the network adapter #1 is cable connected. That fixed the issue for me (ie: on VirtualBox > box settings > Network > Adapter 1 > Advanced > tick "Cable Connected). Or better, add this to your vagrant file:

```
config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|
  vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cableconnected1', 'on']
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply type `vagrant ssh` on the command line / terminal of the host machine (Assuming you've already fired up the machine with `vagrant up`). To quote the [vagrantup.com](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/up.html) website:

> This command will drop you into a full-fledged SSH session