# Connection timeout when starting Vagrant

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laravel, vagrant

I am trying to use Laravel Homestead on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I have installed Vagrant 1.6.5 and Oracle's VM virtual box 4.3.1.

When I am starting my Vagrant by using `vagrant up` command, it is giving me following error:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'laravel/homestead' is available! You currently
==> default: have version '0.1.6'. The latest is version '0.2.0'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8000 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 33060 (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 => 54320 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: try refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25982233/297203

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue for more than one week, Tried all solutions,

```
1. giving SSH username and password
2. Enabling GUI interface
```

Finally got the solution from [this link](http://laravel.io/forum/05-27-2014-laravel-homestead-not-connecting-when-wifi-is-enabled)

Add the `Google public DNS IP` to your `Wifi Settings`

under `Network Preferences > Wifi > Advanced > DNS add IP Address 8.8.8.8`

Worked perfectly. May be this can help someone who have problem in Mac. Thanks Skovmand.

And also make sure that you've latest `Vagrant` and `VMWare`

Comment: Wow, this actually worked. I alternatively connected to a VPN, which also allowed everything to work.