# Why does Vagrant not work right out of the box on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vagrant, virtualization

Windows 7 64-bit here. Went to the [Vagrant stable version downloads page](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads). Downloaded the Windows 64-bit installer, installed using **all recommended defaults**, and rebooted.

Then read their [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/). Opened a command prompt:

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
```

And see the following output:

```
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
```

OK. So far so good. Then I do:

```
vagrant up
```

And here is the output:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'hashicorp/precise32'
    default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32
==> default: Adding box 'hashicorp/precise32' (v1.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise32/versions/1.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
    default:
==> default: Successfully added box 'hashicorp/precise32' (v1.0.0) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise32'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vms_default_1421176231425_15801
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Then I read the next part of the Getting Started Guide:

> Now imagine every project you've ever worked on being this easy to set up.

**LOL**

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: To troubleshoot and/or get that VM working, you could try [enabling GUI mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690124/vagrant-up-timeout/23742373#23742373). That might help provide a clue as to why it doesn't work straight away, as it should.

Comment: Thanks @BrianC (+1) - however I uncommented this section of code in the `Vagrantfile` (to enable GUI mode) and then re-ran `vagrant up`, and nothing is different. Thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm *shocked* that this hasn't received more attention! This is a major tool simply not being functional, or even having minimum viability...Hashicorp? Bueller? Bueller?

Comment: any chance you have Hyper-V installed?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelS (+1) - I don't even know what "Hyper-V" is, so I can't say either way. However, the full steps to reproduce this are in my original question above: I literally installed from those links and used all the recommended defaults (zero customizations).

Comment: Nevermind, Hyper-V is a Windows 8.1 thing.. Can you try to start virtual machine manually via VirtualBox to check and see if the issue is VirtualBox or Vagrant?

Comment: @smeeb I use Vagrant primarily from a Mac but also from Windows. Sometimes I run into issues which are Windows-specific, but for the most part it "just works". On my Win7 laptop I just followed your exact steps and it worked for me. You could check this SO question "[Vagrant stuck connection timeout retrying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying)" which has a lot of possible solutions. I would start by checking if virtualization is enabled in your PC BIOS. Starting VirtualBox manually like MichaelS suggested would also confirm.

Comment: The situation could be because of VirtualBox failed to redirect ports, despite saying 
'**==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)**'
You may have a look at full description in my question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529651/virtualbox-nat-failed-to-redirect-tcp-127-0-0-12222-10-0-2-1522).
I still have no idea how to fix redirection fail(
Please drop a note in my post, if and how you succeed!