# Set a box with Vagrant (VirtualBox's version)

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox

I would try to work with a virtual environment for data science. For that, I use the vagrant's box: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/data-science-toolbox/boxes/dst. 
But, I have the following problem with VirtualBox:

==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot.
 This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.
If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

**

I have tested different versions of VirtualBox (4.3.20, 4.3.18 and 4.3.12), but I have still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried building a Vagrant VM with that data sciences box (on my Mac system) and it worked fine. As the error message mentions, you might want to try enabling GUI mode to see if it provides a clue to the problem in your case.

See my answer here which explains how to enable GUI mode and some other troubleshooting ideas: [vagrantfile - Vagrant up timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690124/vagrant-up-timeout/23742373#23742373).