# Failed to boot vagrant box 'TIME OUT'

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vmware

I'm using vagrant inside the linux VM using VMWare and the hosted machine is windows-base. So it's a virtual machine inside a virtual machine.

So when I try to boot the vagrant box I got this error 
 [image]

When I google I couldn't able to find the exact solution for this but here in this question [Vagrant up timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690124/vagrant-up-timeout) @BrainC pointed out that enable GUI mode from vagrant config file it will give you better idea what exactly going wrong here. but still I couldn't able to find any cause of the problem!

So what's the really issue here... is it because of virtual-machine inside virtual-machine or it's something else.

**UPDATE:** 
 when i enabled gui option in vagrantfile gui opens it shows some error BUT IT happend so fast I couldn't able to see it, so I've recorded the screen and this is what i got

[image]

Comment: are you using a 32 or 64 bits VM ? 32 bits VM can run inside a 64 bits VM but I am not sure about other combination

Comment: Outer vm or the vm that's hosted on Windows is 64bit!