# Vagrant Up (private_network) Error : default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have the following Vagranfile. When I `vagrant up`, I'm getting the following error. **However, if I switch to use a `config.vm.network "public_network"`, everything works fine.**

But I still want to use `config.vm.network "private_network"` so I can assign fixed IP address for development.

[Error]

```
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
```

[Vagrantfile]

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "pef"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.12"
  #config.vm.network "public_network"

  config.vm.synced_folder "C:/Users/user1/myprj", "/home/vagrant"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
     vb.gui = true

     # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
     vb.memory = "1024"

     # For host-only adapter
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected" ]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "Am79C973"]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype2", "Am79C973"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue which is confusing. First thing you need to know, is the problem causing timeout.

If you're using VirtualBox, you can add this to your VagrantFile :

```
   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
     vb.gui = true
```

That will launch VirtualBox window and help you understand the potential error you have during the booting process of your VM.

In my case, I tried several things and ended up raising Vagrant time out to 600 :

```
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 600
```

You can also read to this feed on StackOverflow , it describes the same issue : 
[Vagrant up timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690124/vagrant-up-timeout)