# Vagrant up timeout VirtualBox

Tags: timeout, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a problem with virtualbo, I try run vagrant up on my PC but i get error. I tried fix this problems and I was looking for a solution on web but still doesn't work. Can someone help me how fix this ?

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
default: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to        find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox
default: Box Version: >= 0
default: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
default: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.4.0) for provider: virtualbox
default: Downloading:  https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.4.0/providers/virtualbox.box
default: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.4.0) for 'virtualbox'!
default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead-7
default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
default: Adapter 2: hostonly
default: Forwarding ports...
default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
default: Booting VM...
default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that 
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

I try this run on Ubuntu 15.10 with VirtualBox 5.0.12. On my netbook all works fine but i want work with this project on desktop PC

Ps: I don't have any options with virtualization in my bios

Answer (score 3):

There was several questions like this, but here is one with the biggest number of answers: [Vagrant stuck connection timeout retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575261/vagrant-stuck-connection-timeout-retrying/35211069#35211069), probably you will find solution there.

In my case the problem was 64-bit Debian in box for Vagrant - Virtual Box treated it as 32-bit and I had to change it manually in settings. You will find more precise description in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that after a few days of troubleshooting this issue on a Windows 10 machine it was the virtualization settings in BIOS that were turned off and needed to be turned on.

Once I figured this out and turned on the the two virtualization settings I have not had a problem with SSHing into my VMs. I've had a few other hiccups, but those have been related to my Vagrantfiles or config files and that's just my own customization.

See this answer here also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34305608/6436098